# Batch script that get hostname from list then pings hostname, if result then do stuff

Tags: batch-file

From: [Batch ERRORLEVEL ping response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329749/batch-errorlevel-ping-response/9329923#9329923)
I found this pice  of  code

```
for /f %%i in ('ping racer ^| find /c "(0%% loss)"') do SET MATCHES=%%i
echo %MATCHES%
```

I am trying to replace "racer" with an variable I get from a textfile:

```
for /f %%x in (computers.txt)
```

trying to nest 2 for loops gives me erros

After this I want to do something like this (not tried this code yet):

```
    IF "%MATCHES%"=="0" (

shutdown /h /m \\%%x


) ELSE (

IF (

"%MATCHES%"!=="0"

)

echo "ping failed to %%x" >> failed01.txt

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%a in (computers.txt) do (
  Call :IsPingable %%a && shutdown /h /m \\%%a || echo Ping failed to %%a >> failed01.txt
)
exit /b

:IsPingable comp
ping -n 1 -w 3000 -4 -l 8 "%~1" | Find "TTL=">nul
exit /b
```