# PING exit code different between linux and windows

Tags: linux, windows, networking, tcp, ping

I notice today this behaviour, and it is a weird surprise to me.

linux :

```
ping host_live : exit code 0
ping host_down : exit code 1
ping host_not_found : exit code 1
```

windows 7 :

```
ping host_live : exit code 0
ping host_down : exit code 0
ping host_not_found : exit code 1
```

( host_not_found : I mean, a hostname not resolveable to IP address )

=== Windows ===

Considering the TcpIp stack and utilities were born under unix and copied from the other vendors / OS, which is the rationale of this different behaviour ?

At the start of my batch scripts, how can I detect if the remote party is down ?

Should I deploy on 1200 clients a custom ping utility ?

Comment: I did the  tests with hosts on the same subnet. Windows : if I ping a host down on a different subnet : exit code 1. This can explain the behaviour. My last two questions are still open.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329749/batch-errorlevel-ping-response/13825847

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27748080/2861476) could help.