# redirecting .exe output within batch script to txt file

Tags: batch-file, output, exe, redirect

i am trying to redirect output from an exe(commanline exe) which is being called in from batch file to log file. In this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408673/how-to-ping-multiple-servers-and-return-ip-address-and-hostnames-using-batch-scr) IP addresses of hostnames provided in input.txt are being redirected to result.txt. i am trying to run .exe within same batch script to place those IPs in maintenance mode in my monitoring tool. Script runs fine  and performs the action as expected but it fails to capture the output from .exe. please help.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set OUTPUT_FILE=result.txt
>nul copy nul %OUTPUT_FILE%
for /f %%i in (input.txt) do (
set SERVER_ADDRESS=ADDRESS N/A
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%x in ('ping -n 1 %%i ^&^& echo SERVER_IS_UP') do (
    if %%x==Pinging set SERVER_ADDRESS=%%y
    if %%x==Reply set SERVER_ADDRESS=%%z
    if %%x==SERVER_IS_UP (set SERVER_STATE=UP) else (set SERVER_STATE=DOWN)
)
echo !SERVER_ADDRESS::=!>>%OUTPUT_FILE%
)
start c:\MaintenanceMode.exe ON %OUTPUT_FILE% %USERNAME% >> "c:\result2.txt"
```

---

Output from .exe if i run it directly from command prompt:

```
PS C:\> .\MaintenanceMode.exe ON C:\result.txt username
Not an IP!!
Reading IPs from File: C:\result.txt
Valid Arguments
System put into MM      Host#   10.*.*.*    Status# Success
System put into MM      Host#   10.*.*.*    Status# Success
```

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting the output of the START command, but not the exe.

If you want to use START and redirect the output, then you most execute a new CMD.EXE session and escape the redirection so it occurs within the new session:

```
start cmd /c c:\MaintenanceMode.exe ON %OUTPUT_FILE% %USERNAME% ^>^> "c:\result2.txt"
```

But why are you using START? It would be so much simpler if you simply execute your exe directly:

```
c:\MaintenanceMode.exe ON %OUTPUT_FILE% %USERNAME% >> "c:\result2.txt"
```