# Run multiples CMD to ping and create a txt

Tags: batch-file, logging, cmd, ping

i'm trying to made a batch that run multiples cmd and they made a log file, i already google it but i didn't found any solution about this :(

```
ping google.com >> 1.txt
ping facebook.com >> 2.txt
ping twitter.com >> 3.txt
```

this is an example of what I want to do, start 3 different CMD where a simple ping is made and save a txt (as if were a log)

if I put a start before of the command, it creates the text and the pings, but it doesn't register in the txt file, it shows blank

```
start ping google.com >> 1.txt
start ping facebook.com >> 2.txt
start ping twitter.com >> 3.txt
```

basically, I want that all the commands run at the same time in just one batch file, I don't want to wait that the fist command finished and start the next one

Comment: You can take a look at this ==> [Pinging Multiple PCs and Adding Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636170/pinging-multiple-pcs-and-adding-text?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is trying to redirect the output of `start` which doesn't have any.  Try this

```
start cmd.exe "/c ping google.com >> 1.txt"
start cmd.exe "/c ping facebook.com >> 2.txt"
start cmd.exe "/c ping twitter.com >> 3.txt"
```

Comment: and if the text file contains spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution :

```
@echo off
Title Multi Ping Tester
set URLS=www.twitter.com www.google.com www.facebook.com
For %%a in (%URLS%) do call :test_ping %%a
Exit /b
::**********************************************************
:test_ping
cls
If Exist %1.txt Del %1.txt
start cmd.exe "/c ping -4 -a %1 >> %1.txt"                 
Exit /b
::**********************************************************
```

Comment: this seems to be a very good option, i will implement it as well