# Read webs from a file and ping them with a loop (?)

Tags: batch-file

im making an script to ping different websites. I want to read addresses from a file, ping them one time, and write the results on another text file.

```
echo off
cls

echo "TEST" > %cd%\out.txt
time >> %cd%\out.txt
ping -n 1 google.com>> %cd%\out.txt

pause>null
```

I dont know how to make the loop for pinging and also, how to read line by line from the file. Can anyone help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: You can take a look at this example [Pinging Multiple PCs and Adding Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636170/pinging-multiple-pcs-and-adding-text?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the following should be what you want:

```
@echo off& setlocal
echo google.com>sites.txt
echo yahoo.com>>sites.txt
set cd=.

for /f %%w in (sites.txt) do call :NextSite %%w
exit /b

:NextSite
echo. >>%cd%\out.txt
echo. >>%cd%\out.txt
echo. | time | find "current" >>%cd%\out.txt
ping -n 1 %1 >>%cd%\out.txt
```

The logic starts at the line with the "for" statement; the preceding lines merely set up a test environment.  You will have your own %cd% setting and filename to replace "sites.txt"