# Closing program using Task scheduler

Tags: windows, vb.net, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I want to close a program using Windows task scheduler, so I've created a batch file:

```
TASKKILL /F /IM "Mobile Partner.exe"
```

This script closes the application "Mobile partner" and this trick is working!

My question - is it possible to run this script only if "Mobile Partner" tries to start or the computer is connected to the internet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will kill the process if it is either running or there is an internet connection.

```
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq Mobile Partner.exe" | find /i "Mobile Partner.exe" >nul && taskkill /im "Mobile Partner.exe" /f
ping www.google.co.uk -n 1
if %errorlevel%==0 taskkill /im "Mobile Partner.exe" /f
```

Answer (score 0):

yes in a manner of speaking.  The script would run on the schedule regardless. What you're wanting is to only run the kill command under your conditions.

Here's a SO question about pinging an ip, which could be used to determine if you're connected to the internet [How to check if ping responded or not in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050898/how-to-check-if-ping-responded-or-not-in-a-batch-file)

as for the other, that's a matter to just see if the process 'Mobile partner' is active (a simple WMI call).

Comment: thanks for your reply.
please tell me how to check if the program is running and then run the script.