# Batch file to check whether my network cable is unplugged or not

Tags: batch-file

I am having one application "Lifeline.exe" which is installed on server. To execute this application on client machine I need to create shortcut from server.

Some times one of the switch in the network goes down and user can't access server.

I want to create one batch file which ping to local ip address i.e localhost , if ping status=false then it will execute "Network Error, please contact Administrator".

Comment: how did your attempt at creating that batch file go? Can you post it?

Comment: Pinging `localhost` will _always_ work. Don't you mean you want to ping the server?

Comment: Look here: The script in the accepted answer should do this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050898/how-to-check-if-ping-responded-or-not-in-a-batch-file

Answer (score 1):

You could ping the server and see if it replied.

```
@echo off
ping 192.168.0.1 | find "Reply" >nul
if not %errorlevel%==0 echo Network Error, please contact Administrator
pause >nul
```