# Some commands don't work in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

So I realized that some commands such as "ping" and "netstat" only work when I type them into the CMD, but if I put them in a batch file, they don't work. Any help?

Comment: Why not? What happens when you try to put them in a batch file? How do you know they're not working?

Comment: For ping, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050898/how-to-check-if-ping-responded-or-not-in-a-batch-file) - please be more specific with respect to what these utilities don't seem to do when called from a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to save your file as .bat as file type . Batch scripting and cmd prompt contain slight differences. You may google Batch Scripting for more tutorial about it .