# batch file to check ip address status

Tags: batch-file, networking, ip

I have a batch file which is supposed to echo link is `up` if the ip address is linked (pinging is successful) and should echo link is `down` if not, for some reason if I type in in command prompt

checklink 192.168.0.238

which is not a linked address (suppose to get `down` signal), I get first `up` then I get the correct signal `down`
output is:

```
link is up
link is down
```

Here is the batch file:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
REM checking the state of the current ip addres
set ipaddr=%1
set oldstate=neither
:loop
set state=up
ping -n 1 !ipaddr! >nul: 2>nul:
if not !errorlevel!==0 set state=down
if not !state!==!oldstate! (
    echo.Link is !state!
    set oldstate=!state!
)
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul: 2>nul:
goto :loop
endlocal
```

My question why it does not work initially then it starts working?

Comment: I don't think `errorlevel` is not set properly when you get the successful reply `Destination host unreachable.`  So it will think the ping is successful even when it is not.  Instead of redirecting the `ping` output to `nul`, you should probably evaluate it to see if the word `TTL` is present, which means `up`, otherwise it's `down`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a continuation of my comment above, that `errorlevel` cannot be trusted as a true indicator whether the ping worked because of how it is set when the ping returns `Destination host unreachable.`  Here's an example of what I mean:

```
c:\>ping -n 1 192.168.0.238&echo ERRORLEVEL = !errorlevel!

Pinging 192.168.0.238 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.238:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
ERRORLEVEL = 1

c:\>ping -n 1 192.168.0.238&echo ERRORLEVEL = !errorlevel!

Pinging 192.168.0.238 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from x.x.x.x: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.238:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
ERRORLEVEL = 0

c:\>ping -n 1 192.168.0.238&echo ERRORLEVEL = !errorlevel!

Pinging 192.168.0.238 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.238:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
ERRORLEVEL = 1
```

This code seems to work a lot better:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

REM checking the state of the current ip addres
set ipaddr=%1
set oldstate=neither

:loop
set state=down
for /f "skip=2 tokens=6 delims= " %%i in ('ping -n 1 !ipaddr!') do if "%%i"=="TTL=128" set state=up

if not !state!==!oldstate! (
    echo.Link is !state!
    set oldstate=!state!
)

ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul: 2>nul:
goto :loop

endlocal
```

When I run `checklink 192.168.0.238`, I get `link is down` and it never toggles to `up`.  When I run `checklink 127.0.0.1`, I get `link is up`.

Comment: `for /f "skip=2 tokens=4" %%i in ('ping -n 1 -l 50 !ipaddr!') do if "%%i"=="bytes=50" set state=up` This works for me.

Comment: suggested improvement, replace : `echo.Link is !state!` with `echo.Link is !state! at %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%` to display the current time for each link state change.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set IPaddy=%~1

:loop
Call :IsPingable %IPaddy% && (echo %IPaddy% is up & exit /b) || (echo %IPaddy% is down & goto :loop)

:IsPingable <comp>
ping -n 1 -w 3000 -4 -l 8 "%~1" | Find "TTL=">nul  
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

Script updated to display current date and time when a change occurs and working with any TTL value
(looks like original script `checklink.cmd` comes from [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050898/how-to-check-if-ping-responded-or-not-in-a-batch-file/3050945#3050945)).

NB: Proposition with `bytes=50` was not working for all locales.

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

REM checking the state of the current ip address
set ipaddr=%1
set oldstate=neither

if x!ipaddr!==x (
echo Missing ip address argument
goto :end
)

:loop
set state=down

for /f %%i in ('ping -n 1 !ipaddr! ^| findstr "TTL="') do (
set state=up)

if not !state!==!oldstate! (
    echo.Link is !state! at %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%
    set oldstate=!state!
)

ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul: 2>nul:
goto :loop

:end
endlocal
```