# Batch Script to constantly ping, when fails use logic to disable and enable network adapters

Tags: batch-file, network-programming

I am looking for a batch script that can constantly ping a server.  When the ping fails there would be logic to stop the ping, then disable and enable network adapters.

Comment: See the answer to [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050898/how-to-check-if-ping-responded-or-not-in-a-batch-file) It carries out a very similar task to what you're look for. If you need clarification on anything, tag me in a comment and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```
@echo off&cls

:loop
Echo connection Test...
ping www.google.com >nul || (
  Echo Reseting the connection...
  netsh interface set interface "Name of the connection" Disable
  netsh interface set interface "Name of the connection" Enable
)
::Change the value (300) to in/decrease the time value between 2 tests
ping localhost -n 300 >nul
goto:loop
```