# finding a numerical string range in a text file with batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a very basic batch file that basically just pings Google then logs the results in a text file which I have been using as a simple way of testing WiFi connection consistency.

What I'm trying to do is make a second batch file that searches the log txt for any lost packets ranging from 1-4 or find a % loss greater than 0 (outputing results in a second txt file would be a plus too) but I'm not quite knowledgeable in batch so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the data in the WiFi connection log look like? Can you include a sample?

Comment: Is it not easier to check if the ping responds immediately and output that to a textfile, without outputting every ping to a textfile? If so I recommend looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050898/how-to-check-if-ping-responded-or-not-in-a-batch-file)