# Batch script errorlevel code issue. can any one be of assisstance

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file to tell if the internet is down at our school. Sometimes it is a network issue, and sometimes it is a website issue. here` is the code I have so far, feel free to edit or copy and paste. I am new to batch files, and this is my first question.

```
@ echo off 
color B
goto pingwifi
:pingwifi
cls
ping -n 5 172.16.1.1
if errorlevel 1 (
color c
msg * WIFI DOWN
goto pingwifi
)
:pingjostens
cls
ping -n 5 192.189.112.185
if errorlevel 1 (
color c
msg * JOSTENS DOWN
goto pingwifi
)
goto pingjostens
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Looks like you want to share some results of hard work. You may do so, but please abide the rules of this site. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on how to do it

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [Ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if ping responded or not in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050898/how-to-check-if-ping-responded-or-not-in-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

There are way better methods, but by just amending your script:

```
@echo off 
:pingwifi
color B
cls
echo Pinging Wifi
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 >nul
if %errorlevel%==1 (
 color c
 msg * WIFI DOWN
 timeout /T 60
 goto pingwifi
) else (
goto pingjostens
)
:pingjostens
cls
echo Pinging Jostens
ping -n 5 jost >nul
if %errorlevel%==1 (
 color c
 msg * JOSTENS DOWN
 timeout /T 60
 goto pingjostens
)
goto pingwifi
```

It will ping `Wifi`, if up, it will ping Jostens, if `wifi` is down it will print the message and wait 60 seconds and retry ping to `wifi`

If `wifi` is up and Jostens is down, it will print message and retry after 60 seconds. If both are up it will just loop infinitely.