# How can you create pop up messages in a batch script?

Tags: popup, batch-file

I need to know how to make popup messages in batch scripts **without** using VBScript or KiXtart or any other external scripting/programming language.
I have zero clue about this... had no starting point even.
I am aware of `NET SEND` but the Messenger service is disabled in my current environment.

Comment: First link from Google:  http://www.robvanderwoude.com/usermessages.php

Comment: I saw that but, he's using VBscript and Kixtart while I wanted to know if it's possible using CMD itself. The NET SEND command is somewhat different since I have used it to send a user messages remotely. But, in my current environment Messenger service is disabled. Any other ways to do this?

Comment: Not without external scripting, no.

Comment: OK, I guess just post the above link as an answer I wanna close this question in that case. Sad I can't do this within CMD :(

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of [How can I open a message box in a Windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774175/how-can-i-open-a-message-box-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a popup/message box from a Windows batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774175/show-a-popup-message-box-from-a-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

With regard to LittleBobbyTable's answer - NET SEND does not work on Vista or Windows 7. It has been replaced by MSG.EXE

There is a crude solution that works on all versions of Windows - A crude popup message can be sent by STARTing a new cmd.exe window that closes once a key is pressed.

```
start "" cmd /c "echo Hello world!&echo(&pause"
```

If you want your script to pause until the message box is dismissed, then you can add the /WAIT option.

```
start "" /wait cmd /c "echo Hello world!&echo(&pause"
```

Comment: Hmm I didnt even think of that. So primitive yet effective. Thanks!

Comment: Why the `echo(&`? Won't `echo.&` work just as well? And without unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: It turns out `ECHO.` can fail under certain circumstances, and `ECHO(` never fails. It looks like it would cause problems with unbalanced parens, but it actually works very well. I admit it does look awkward.

Comment: Does it continue even after a reboot?

Comment: @AshishK - Of course not. No process survives a reboot. There could be a logical process that resumes (restarts) upon reboot, but that would be a new physical process that continues a logical one. But that is not relevant here.

Comment: James K when dbenham use something, then just use it with your eyes closed :0 he is the stephane chazelas with bash but for batch

Answer (score 67):

```
msg * "Enter Your Message"
```

Does this help ?

Comment: Works on Windows 7 but not 10

Comment: @M. Mimpen here is a screenshot from my virtualbox install: http://i.imgur.com/blWLxdH.png

Comment: @GM-Script-Writer-62850 Apparently, it is only installed on Business and higher editions. Source: http://superuser.com/questions/269880/how-can-i-install-msg-exe

Comment: msg.exe does not come with Windows 10 Home, however you can copy the exe and exe.mui file from a pro to a home.

Comment: How to pause the script until the message box is dismissed?

Comment: to pause the script use /W

Answer (score 28):

You can take advantage of `CSCRIPT.EXE` or `WSCRIPT.EXE` (which have been present in every version of Windows since, I believe, Windows 95) like this:

```
echo msgbox "Hey! Here is a message!" > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
cscript /nologo %tmp%\tmp.vbs
del %tmp%\tmp.vbs
```

or

```
echo msgbox "Hey! Here is a message!" > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
wscript %tmp%\tmp.vbs
del %tmp%\tmp.vbs
```

You could also choose the more customizeable `PopUp` command. This example gives you a 10 second window to click OK, before timing out:

```
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
echo WScript.Quit (WshShell.Popup( "You have 10 seconds to Click 'OK'." ,10 ,"Click OK", 0)) >> %tmp%\tmp.vbs
cscript /nologo %tmp%\tmp.vbs
if %errorlevel%==1 (
  echo You Clicked OK
) else (
  echo The Message timed out.
)
del %tmp%\tmp.vbs
```

In their above context, both `cscript` and `wscript` will act the same. When called from a batch file, bot `cscript` and `wscript` will pause the batch file until they finish their script, then allow the file to continue.

When called manually from the command prompt, `cscript` will not return control to the command prompt until it is finished, while `wscript` will create a seprate thread for the execution of it's script, returning control to the command prompt even before it's script has finished.

Other methods discussed in this thread do not cause the execution of batch files to pause while waiting for the message to be clicked on.  Your selection will be dictated by your needs.

**Note:** Using this method, multiple button and icon configurations are available to cover various **yes/no/cancel/abort/retry** queries to the user: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156593.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Few more ways (in all of them the script waits for button pressing unlike `msg.exe`).

**1)** The geekiest and hackiest - it uses the IEXPRESS to create small exe that will create a pop-up with a single button ([it can create two more types of pop-up messages](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5901)).Works on EVERY windows from XP and above:

```
;@echo off
;setlocal

;set ppopup_executable=popupe.exe
;set "message2=%~1"
;
;del /q /f %tmp%\yes >nul 2>&1
;
;copy /y "%~f0" "%temp%\popup.sed" >nul 2>&1

;(echo(FinishMessage=%message2%)>>"%temp%\popup.sed";
;(echo(TargetName=%cd%\%ppopup_executable%)>>"%temp%\popup.sed";
;(echo(FriendlyName=%message1_title%)>>"%temp%\popup.sed"
;
;iexpress /n /q /m %temp%\popup.sed
;%ppopup_executable%
;rem del /q /f %ppopup_executable% >nul 2>&1

;pause

;endlocal
;exit /b 0


[Version]
Class=IEXPRESS
SEDVersion=3
[Options]
PackagePurpose=InstallApp
ShowInstallProgramWindow=1
HideExtractAnimation=1
UseLongFileName=0
InsideCompressed=0
CAB_FixedSize=0
CAB_ResvCodeSigning=0
RebootMode=N
InstallPrompt=%InstallPrompt%
DisplayLicense=%DisplayLicense%
FinishMessage=%FinishMessage%
TargetName=%TargetName%
FriendlyName=%FriendlyName%
AppLaunched=%AppLaunched%
PostInstallCmd=%PostInstallCmd%
AdminQuietInstCmd=%AdminQuietInstCmd%
UserQuietInstCmd=%UserQuietInstCmd%
SourceFiles=SourceFiles
[SourceFiles]
SourceFiles0=C:\Windows\System32\
[SourceFiles0]
%FILE0%=


[Strings]
AppLaunched=subst.exe
PostInstallCmd=<None>
AdminQuietInstCmd=
UserQuietInstCmd=
FILE0="subst.exe"
DisplayLicense=
InstallPrompt=
;
```

Example Usage (if you save the script as `expPopup.bat`):

```
call expPopup.bat "my Message"
```

**2)** Using `MSHTA`. Also works on every windows machine from XP and above (despite yhe OP do not wants "external" languages the jsvascript here is minimized).Should be saved as `.bat`:

```
@if (true == false) @end /*!
@echo off
mshta "about:<script src='file://%~f0'></script><script>close()</script>" %*
goto :EOF */

alert("Hello, world!");
```

or in one line:

```
mshta "about:<script>alert('Hello, world!');close()</script>"
```

or

```
mshta "javascript:alert('message');close()"
```

or

```
mshta.exe vbscript:Execute("msgbox ""message"",0,""title"":close")
```

**3)** Here's parametrized `.bat/jscript` hybrid (should be saved as `bat`) .It again uses jscript despite the OP request but as it is a bat it can be called as a bat file without worries.It uses [POPUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f(v=vs.84).aspx) which allows a little bit more control than the more populae [MSGBOX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x(v=vs.84).aspx).It uses WSH ,but not MSHTA like in the example above.

```
 @if (@x)==(@y) @end /***** jscript comment ******
     @echo off

     cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%~nx0" %*
     exit /b 0

 @if (@x)==(@y) @end ******  end comment *********/
 

var wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var args=WScript.Arguments;
var title=args.Item(0);

var timeout=-1;
var pressed_message="button pressed";
var timeout_message="timedout";
var message="";

function printHelp() {
    WScript.Echo(title + "[-title Title] [-timeout m] [-tom \"Time-out message\"] [-pbm \"Pressed button message\"]  [-message \"pop-up message\"]");
}

if (WScript.Arguments.Length==1){
    runPopup();
    WScript.Quit(0);
}

if (args.Item(1).toLowerCase() == "-help" ||  args.Item(1).toLowerCase() == "-h" ) {
    printHelp();
    WScript.Quit(0);
}

if (WScript.Arguments.Length % 2 == 0 ) {
    WScript.Echo("Illegal arguments ");
    printHelp();
    WScript.Quit(1);
}

for (var arg = 1 ; arg<args.Length;arg=arg+2) {
        
    if (args.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-title") {
        title = args.Item(arg+1);
    }
    
    if (args.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-timeout") {
        timeout = parseInt(args.Item(arg+1));
        if (isNaN(timeout)) {
            timeout=-1;
        }
    }
    
    if (args.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-tom") {
        timeout_message = args.Item(arg+1);
    }
    
    if (args.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-pbm") {
        pressed_message = args.Item(arg+1);
    }
    
    if (args.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-message") {
        message = args.Item(arg+1);
    }
}
 
function runPopup(){
    var btn = wshShell.Popup(message, timeout, title, 0x0 + 0x10);
     
    switch(btn) {
        // button pressed.
        case 1:
            WScript.Echo(pressed_message);
            break;

        // Timed out.
        case -1:
           WScript.Echo(timeout_message);
           break;
    }
}

runPopup();
```

example usage (it will wait 10 seconds to press the yes button):

```
jsPopup.bat -title CoolTitile -t 10 -tom "time out" -pbm "press the button please" -message "love and peace"
```

**4)** and one  `jscript.net/.bat` hybrid (should be saved as `.bat`) .This time it uses `.NET` and compiles a small `.exe` file that could be deleted:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /****** silent jscript comment ******

@echo off
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       compile the script    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal


::if exist "%~n0.exe" goto :skip_compilation

:: searching the latest installed .net framework
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:d /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*"') do (
    if exist "%%v\jsc.exe" (
        rem :: the javascript.net compiler
        set "jsc=%%~dpsnfxv\jsc.exe"
        goto :break_loop
    )
)
echo jsc.exe not found && exit /b 0
:break_loop



call %jsc% /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~f0" 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       end of compilation    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:skip_compilation

::
::::::::::
"%~n0.exe" %*
::::::::
::
endlocal
exit /b 0

****** end of jscript comment ******/

import System;
import System.WIndows;
import System.Windows.Forms

var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
MessageBox.Show(arguments[1],arguments[0]);
```

Example usage:

```
netPopUp.bat "Roger That"
```

**5)** and at the end one single call to powershell that creates a pop-up (can be called from command line or from batch if powershell is installed):

```
powershell [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("""System.Windows.Forms""");[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::show("""Hello World""", """My PopUp Message Box""")
```

**6)** Though `msg` solution is already post as answer here's a better way to be used:

```
msg * /self /w "hello world"
```

`/self` is a not documented switch that will force msg to send the message only to the current user.

Answer (score 6):

msg * Hello world

works for me..

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple beacuse i have created a couple lines of code that will do this for you

So set a variable as msg and then use this code. it popup in a VBS message box.

CODE:

```
@echo off
echo %msg% >vbs.txt
copy vbs.txt vbs.vbs
del vbs.txt
start vbs.vbs
timeout /t 1
del vbs.vbs
cls
```

This is just something i came up with it should work for most of your message needs and it also works with Spaces unlike some batch scripts

Answer (score 1):

So, i present cmdmsg.bat.

The code is:

```
@echo off
echo WScript.Quit MsgBox(%1, vbYesNo) > #.vbs
cscript //nologo #.vbs
echo. >%ERRORLEVEL%.cm
del #.vbs
exit /b
```

And a example file:

```
@echo off 
cls 
call cmdmsg "hi select yes or no"

if exist "6.cm" call :yes
if exist "7.cm" call :no

:yes
cls
if exist "6.cm" del 6.cm
if exist "7.cm" del 7.cm
echo.
echo you selected yes
echo.
pause >nul
exit /b

:no
cls
if exist "6.cm" del 6.cm
if exist "7.cm" del 7.cm
echo.
echo aw man, you selected no
echo.
pause >nul
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

I put together a script based on the good answers here & in other posts

You can set title timeout & even sleep to schedule it for latter & \n for new line

also you get back the key press into a variable (`%pop.key%`).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60087350/12327655) is my code

Comment: The question explicitly states `without using VBScript or KiXtart or any other external scripting/programming language`

Comment: I see, but only 4 out of the other 10 answers are using `msg`, `Net send` (that he cant use), `echo`, so I just picked the best answers into one file, & after all its not a third party app & once you place it in a path folder you don't need to know any scripting/programming language, you just enter `popup` & your message

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use `NET SEND` as documented on [Rob van der Woude's site](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/usermessages.php).

Otherwise, you'll need to use an external scripting program.  Batch files are really intended to send messages via `ECHO`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to make a message, here's how:

First open notpad and type:

```
msg "Message",0,"Title"
```

and save it as Message.vbs.

Now in your batch file type:

```
Message.vbs %*
```

Answer (score 0):

### `msg * message goes here`

That method is very simple and easy and should work in any batch file i believe. The only "downside" to this method is that it can only show 1 message at once, if there is more than one message it will show each one after the other depending on the order you put them inside the code. Also make sure there is a different looping or continuous operator in your batch file or it will close automatically and only this message will appear. If you need a "quiet" background looping opperator, heres one:

### `pause >nul`

That should keep it running but then it will close after a button is pressed.

Also to keep all the commands "quiet" when running, so they just run and dont display that they were typed into the file, just put the following line at the beginning of the batch file:

### `@echo off`

I hope all these tips helped!