# How to create a repeated popup reminder mesage with batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, popup, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to create a popup reminder message with batch scrip, that will repeat the popup message every one hour?
This is a part of a long batch script and i cant use any other utility or script. It has to be batch script.

Comment: Batch can't do pop-ups. Use vbscript instead. It's technically not third party, since it comes installed with Windows.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25925201/388389

Comment: I cant use vb script as because this is a part of long batch script.

Comment: npocmaka's suggestion for the win.`mshta "javascript:alert('hi!');close()"`

Comment: This script for one time. but how do i repeat that?

Answer (score 0):

If all what is needed is a popup message every hour, include the following line in the batch file

```
start "" /b cmd /q /e /c">nul 2>&1 (for /l %%a in (0) do (msg console this is the message & ping -n 3601 localhost ))"
```

This will spawn a background `cmd` instance that will use `msg` to show the popup and `ping` to wait, all inside an infinite loop.

**edited** to adapt to comments

As I said, maybe the best way to handle it is to leave to the scheduler the message sending, and control the task from a script or command line

This is a copy/paste/change of an existing code i had at hand that wraps argument passing to `schtasks`. The basic idea is

a) Create a task to send the message

```
popup.cmd create taskName "this is the message to send each hour"
```

b) The popup task can be enabled / disabled when needed

```
popup.cmd disable taskName
popup.cmd enable taskName
```

c) When not needed, the task can be removed

```
popup.cmd remove taskName
```

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Where the tasks will be created
    set "tasksFolder=PopUpTasks"

    rem Get the task name from arguments
    call :getTaskName "%~2" taskName

    rem Check list of arguments 
    set "command="
    for %%a in ( 
        create list remove enable disable status run 
    ) do if not defined command if /i "%%~a"=="%~1" (
        set "command=%%a"
        rem List and creation commands have different arguments
        if "%%~a"=="create" ( 
            call :create "%tasksFolder%\%taskName%" "%~3"
        ) else if "%%~a"=="list" ( 
            call :list "%tasksFolder%"
        ) else ( 
            rem The rest of the commands require a valid task name
            rem so we first test and if everything is OK, continue

            call :checkTaskExist "%tasksFolder%\%taskName%" && (
                call :%%~a "%tasksFolder%\%taskName%"
            ) || (
                call :noTask "%tasksFolder%\%taskName%"
            )
        )
    )

    rem If something failed or if we did not found a valid command, show usage
    if errorlevel 1         call :showUsage
    if not defined command  call :showUsage

    goto :eof

:create taskName message
    if "%~2"=="" exit /b 1
    schtasks /create /f /tn "%~1" /sc HOURLY /mo 1 /np /tr "msg.exe console \"%~2\""
    goto :eof

:remove taskName
    schtasks /delete /f /tn "%~1" 
    goto :eof

:enable taskName
    schtasks /change /enable /tn "%~1" 
    goto :eof

:disable taskName
    schtasks /change /disable /tn "%~1" 
    goto :eof

:status taskName
    schtasks /query /tn "%~1" 
    goto :eof

:run taskName 
    schtasks /run /tn "%~1" 
    goto :eof

:list tasksFolder
    schtasks /query /v /fo list /tn "%~1\\"
    goto :eof

:getTaskName taskName returnVar
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "taskName=%~1"
    if "%~1"=="" for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ("%__cd__:\=.%") do set "taskName=%%a.%%b.%~n0"
    endlocal & set "%~2=%taskName%"
    goto :eof

:checkTaskExist taskName
    >nul 2>nul schtasks /query /tn "%~1" 
    exit /b %errorlevel%

:noTask
    echo(
    echo(ERROR: The requested task ["%~1"] does not exist
    exit /b 1

:showUsage
    (
        echo(
        echo( Usage:
        echo(
        echo(  %~n0 COMMAND ["taskName"] ["message"]
        echo(
        echo( With COMMAND :
        echo(    CREATE  "taskName" "message"
        echo(    REMOVE  "taskName" 
        echo(    ENABLE  "taskName" 
        echo(    DISABLE "taskName"
        echo(    STATUS  "taskName"
        echo(    RUN     "taskName"
        echo(    LIST
        echo( 
    ) & exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Comment: getting an error 
C:\Users\Plbn>%%a was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @AriDey, the code is indended for batch file usage. From command line, replace `%%a` with `%a`

Comment: It worked but the problem it is not working when i close the cmd window and in case of my script it is not possible to keep the cmd window open. So is it possible to close the cmd window and still run the script?

Comment: @AriDey, sorry, the code is intended to be used inside a running batch file. Under the new indicated scenario, I think it is easier to create a scheduled task to execute the `msg` command each hour and use scripts or commands to enable/disable the task as needed.

Comment: even i need this code for a batch file....... but only problem is that when i run the code it keeps cmd window open. is it possible to  to run the code with out keeping cmd open?

Comment: @AriDey, answer updated. Probably most of the code is not necessary, but i had it at hand.