# Add title and buttons to message box in batch

Tags: batch-file, messagebox

This is probably a very basic question but I have been searching for awhile and can't make out wether it is possible to add a title and buttons to a msg box in a batch file like you would a msgbox in vb?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The `TITLE` command. Other than that. No.  There is not message box functionality with batch.

Comment: Thanks, what is the syntax for adding title attribute to msg?

Comment: Open up a cmd prompt and type: `title /?`

Comment: @Squashman I think think the OP points to the `msg` command

Comment: `msg` command has not so many options and is not available on machines without terminal services (home editions e.g.) . You can check [jspopup.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/jspopup.bat)  and use it like `jspopup.bat -title "sometitle"  -pbm "yey" -message "this is pop-up"`  . For more info `jspopup.bat -h`

Comment: here are more ways to create a pop-up message - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25925201/388389

Comment: The CHOICE program is probably the lowest common denominator for allowing users to choose something in a .BAT file. So it would be the best choice if you want the batch file to run on more versions of Windows, and don't mind the rather primitive look.

Comment: Does that run from terminal only? As opposed to a pop up GUI