# Batch file, message box always on top

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, messagebox

Actually I have this code:

```
echo msgbox "My Message",0,"Title" > %tmp%\tmp.vbs 
wscript %tmp%\tmp.vbs
del %tmp%\tmp.vbs
```

As you know, it show a message box. I want this message box stay always on top, because if my code open a program while the message box is focus, for example:

```
start /d "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2017" Photoshop.exe
```

It obviously open PS but the message box goes back.

I hope you can help me!

Thank you!

Comment: Possible dupilcate of [How can you create pop up messages in a batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514475)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to replace your `0`:

```bat
MsgBox "My Message",vbInformation+vbSystemModal,"Title"
```

---

You can even have a little fun and run it directly from within the batch file, carry on working in other windows, but leave the batch waiting for it to be closed.

**wMSG.cmd**

```bat
<!-- :StartCmd
@Echo Waiting . . .
@CScript //Nologo "%~f0?.wsf"
@Choice /M "Was that okay"
@If ErrorLevel 2 Echo Sorry!
@Pause
@Exit /B
:StartWSF -->
<Job><Script Language="vbScript">
MsgBox "My Message",vbInformation+vbSystemModal,"Title"
</Script></Job>
```

---

*`vbInformation+vbSystemModal` can be replaced with the values: `64+4096`*

Comment: It worked perfectly :) , but I used to put 0+64 which show an Information Message icon. I replaced the 0 with vbSystemModal but now I can´t have the icon. CanI have the icon and the vbSystemModa at the same time?

Comment: @SantiagoCuartasRmrz, you asked a specific question, using only `0` and I answered it. Please, in future, ask the question you wanted to ask instead of using fake information and hoping that responders will be kind enough to revisit their answers. **I have updated my answer to incorporate your request**;  _if the solution works for you click the large check mark, to the left of my answer, to accept it._