# Redirect stdout and stderr from inside a batch file

Tags: batch-file, stdout, stderr

Is there a way to redirect stdout and stderr for a batch file from inside it.

I'm imagining something like

```
set STDOUT=stdout.log
echo Some text
a.exe
b.exe
c.exe
```

Where both `Some text`, and the output of `a.exe`, `b.exe` and `c.exe` would go to `stdout.log`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is more efficient to redirect once for the entire collection of commands than it is to redirect (with append) each individual command. It takes time to intialize the redirection. It may not be noticable for a few redirected commands, but if done in a loop with many iterations, it can become quite significant.

One method is to enclose the entire block of redirected commands within parentheses and redirect outside the parentheses

```
>stdout.log 2>&1 (
  echo Some text
  a.exe
  b.exe
  c.exe
)
```

Another option is to put your commands in a subroutine and redirect the CALL

```
call :redirect >stdout.log 2>&1
exit /b

:redirect
echo Some text
a.exe
b.exe
c.exe
exit /b
```

Comment: What is the way to put the log filename into a variable?

Comment: Awesome trick! Note that with the first method using parentheses, closing parentheses *within* the outer block must be escaped with a caret ^. And if you pipe the output, each closing parenthesis requires three carets--see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12976840/550712.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you need to redirect and append stdout to your file (`1>> %STDOUT%`) and connect stderr to stdout (`2>&1`):

```
set STDOUT=stdout.log
echo Some text 1>> %STDOUT% 2>&1
a.exe 1>> %STDOUT% 2>&1
b.exe 1>> %STDOUT% 2>&1
c.exe 1>> %STDOUT% 2>&1
```

@EitanT correctly noted that your question doesn't necessarily imply writing both stderr and stdout into the same file. So for completeness, here's a version writing into separated files:

```
set STDOUT=stdout.log
set STDERR=stderr.log
echo Some text 1>> %STDOUT% 2>> %STDERR%
a.exe 1>> %STDOUT% 2>> %STDERR%
b.exe 1>> %STDOUT% 2>> %STDERR%
c.exe 1>> %STDOUT% 2>> %STDERR%
```

Comment: +1: You don't have to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`... if you want you can redirect them to separate logs.

Comment: Of course you don't have to, but I thought he wanted to do exactly that: _...to redirect stdout **and** stderr..._

Comment: Yes, redirect both of them but not necessarily to the same location. Never mind, I'm just nitpicking...