# SQLPLUS - Multiple sql statements from command line

Tags: windows, oracle, sqlplus

I have an Oracle 11 instance on Windows 2003 R2.

I run this to get the output as shown below:

```
C:\>echo select count(*) from v$session; | sqlplus -s zabbix/pwd@localhost:
```

1521/orcl

```
  COUNT(*)
  ----------
       31
```

But, I want the output to just be 31, and not with the column header and the lines below it - something to the effect of `SET HEADING OFF` from within SQL*Plus.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639704/sqlplus-statement-from-command-line) which suggested using the `-e` option for `echo`, but that either doesn't seem to work on Windows or I am missing something.

```
C:\>echo -e "set heading off; \n select count(*) from v$session;" | sqlplus -s zabbix/pwd@localhost:1521/orcl

SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "-e "set he..." - rest of line ignored.
```

This is the exact command mentioned in the post I referenced above:

```
C:\>echo -e "select 1 from dual; \n select 2 from dual;" | sqlplus -s zabbix/pwd@localhost:1521/orcl

SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "-e "select..." - rest of line ignored.
```

I do not see a SQL*Plus flag I can use (like `-s` I used above for silence) to turn heading off. Hence trying this method!

What can I do to make it work on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit messy, but you can do:

```
C:>(echo set heading off & echo select count(*^^^) from v$session; & echo exit;) | sqlplus -s zabbix/pwd@localhost:1521/orcl

        53
```

The `^^^)` part [is to escape the parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12976351/266304) in the `count(*)`, within the parentheses wrapping the two echo commands together - which provides a single input for SQL*Plus.

This has a blank line at the top; you might prefer to use `set pagesize 0` instead of `set heading off`:

```
C:>(echo set pages 0 & echo select count(*^^^) from v$session; & echo exit;) | sqlplus -s zabbix/pwd@localhost:1521/orcl
        53
```

You can put multiple settings in one set command if you need to, as well.

Alternatively, just put all your commands in a script file, e.g. `test.sql`:

```
set pages 0
select count(*) from v$session;
exit
```

and then run that with:

```
sqlplus -s zabbix/pwd@localhost:1521/orcl @test
```

Comment: The syntax with 'pages 0' works great. Thank you Alex!

Comment: Actually, the leading spaces in the output value doesn't work with zabbix for me.

Comment: I mean, instead of          
select count(*) from v$session;
COUNT(*)
--------------
             39
I need:                                    
select trim(count(*)) from v$session;
COUNT(*)
-------------
39   
When I use echo:                               
(echo set pages 0 & echo select trim(LIMIT_VALUE) from v$resource_limit where RESOURCE_NAME='sessions'; & echo exit;) | "C:\Program Files\Zabbix\sqlplus.exe" -s zabbix/pwd@localhost:1521/orcl
    I get - 'from was unexpected at this time.'  Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you escape the inner  closing parenthesis again, with `^^^)`

Comment: Just came here to say that it worked after escaping the ).. Thank you again Alex, really appreciate it.