# Messages on command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to show the result of my function as a pop up message.

This is the code: `for /f "delims=" %%i in (1.txt) do (set MyResult= %MyName% %%i && net user %%i /domain | find /I "password last set")`

I want to show the result of the "do" function in the pop up box.

the result shows the last time the input user changed his/hers password.

I don't want to use `VBscript`, i just want it in `bat`. :)

thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't think it is possible with pure `batch`, unless you have a custom application whose only purpose is to echo its argument into a dialog box. VBscript is [not that hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774175/how-can-i-open-a-message-box-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch this and you'll see what it shows, and is as near as a popup window:

```
@echo off
echo in window 1
pause
start "" /w "%comspec%" /c "mode con: cols=26 lines=5 & color 4E & echo.&echo       Feed the DOG&echo.&  echo  Press a key to continue&pause>nul"
echo back in window 1
pause
```

This code might work for you: and you can adjust the 26 character wide and 5 line window size, and positioning.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (1.txt) do (
 set "MyResult=%MyName% %%i"
   for /f delims=" %%j in ('net user %%i /domain ^| find /I "password last set" ') do (
     start "" /w "%comspec%" /c "mode con: cols=26 lines=5 & color 4E & echo.&echo %%j &echo.&  echo  Press a key to continue&pause>nul"

  )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work on windows 7,Vista,xp (i think) but not on windows 8 or Windows 'Home' editions.

```
msg * %variable%
```