# Run MessageBoxA from Rundll32.exe

Tags: cmd, rundll32

I'm trying to run a `MessageBoxA` from `User32.dll` with `Rundll32.exe`.
As I see in Microsoft references Rundll.exe is for 16-bit applications while Rundll32.exe is for 32-bit ones.
So I write this command :

```
Rundll32.exe User32.dll,MessageBoxA 0,"Text","Title",0
```

But nothing shows!
I think there is something wrong with my syntax. Is there anyway to show a `MessageBoxA` from `Rundll32.exe`?

Comment: [Don't use RunDll for arbitrary DLLs/functions; it was never designed for this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643). How about displaying the message box using [VBScript](https://ss64.com/vb/msgbox.html) or [PowerShell](https://michlstechblog.info/blog/powershell-show-a-messagebox/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a popup/message box from a Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774175/show-a-popup-message-box-from-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: It shouldn't be used in scripts and whatnot, but if you are testing something or just doing it for a here-and-right-now thing, it's fine as that is what it is useful for, despite any other explicit or implicit purpose the creators may have had for it, just be responsible and make sure others don't ever misunderstand and place it in a script (i probably wouldn't even tell anyone out of fear of that) --- that said, security risks, and all that - plus obsolete! not probably going to work on most newer windows systems!