# Confirmation message after successful installation

Tags: batch-file

i need to write code in batch file for install application, after installation has finished, i want to pop up confirmation message (either prompt or echo) before exit. How do i write it ?

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cls
echo.
echo wait for installation
msiexec.exe /i filename.msi /qb /passive

[what should i write here]

exit /B
```

Comment: Check the answer to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774175/show-a-popup-message-box-from-a-windows-batch-file) question.

Comment: Her you have a really good answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25925236/8538799

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a popup/message box from a Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774175/show-a-popup-message-box-from-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: Simpler: `start "Installation complete^!" /Wait cmd /C "cls & mode 40,3 & echo/& pause & exit"`