# Is it possible to raise a message-box that remains after the application exits?

Tags: winapi, mfc

Our client-server system allows the server to remotely terminate a client session, which involves broadcasting a message to the Windows client workstation - in response all client applications are terminated.

In case the user is confused by this (perhaps they are away when the shutdown happens and return to an empty screen), displaying a popup/message-box e.g. "Server terminated your session" would be great - except the process displaying the popup must also exit, we don't want any modules to hang around

Is there a way to display a modeless popup message which persists until the user clicks it, even after the process raising it has ended?

Comment: You can start a system's process, look at ideas in there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774175/show-a-popup-message-box-from-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: Aha, sometimes the simple ways _are_ the best

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use [MessageBox function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) to pop up the message box at the end of the program.

```
MessageBox(NULL, L"Server terminated your session", L"title", MB_OK);
return 0;
```

Comment: Are you somehow suggesting that a message box would survive process termination?